# Document Provider's dismissGrantingAccessToURL does not work in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, ios8.3, document-provider

I build my app with Document Picker Extension & Document Porvider Extension and they worked well before iOS8.3.

With iOS 8.3, nothing happened if I called **dismissGrantingAccessToURL**. View controller of Picker did not dismiss and Host app's delegate function **didPickDocumentAtURL** was not called. There was not any error or warning message. It just...nothing happened!!!, like I did not call this function.

Anyone also has this issue?

XCode: 6.3
iOS: 8.3

Comment: i'm experiencing exactly the same problem, did you find what is causing this? If not maybe we should start a bounty for this?

Comment: We have found why it wasn't working. Not sure you have the same problem, but anyway - our UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController had a property named "navigationController" that was storing some child view controller, it was working fine in 8.2, but looks like something have changed in view hierarchy in 8.3 and it conflicted, so we just renamed that property to "navController" and that's it!

Comment: Thank you wirrwarr. Sorry for forgetting to update this thread. 

Before 8.3, picker's navigation controller can't be accessed,  self.navigationController is nil. Thus I create the property with same name and allocate it manually. Except iCloud, most apps has 2 navigation bars, one is picker's native navigation bar and the other is app's navigation bar.

To solve it quickly, I rename my navigation controller.

I'm considering that whether we should directly use native navigation or not. In fact, 2 navigation bars waste too much height when we run the app at iPhone 5/5s, or even worse on 4s.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by removing the local property named navigationController that we redefined in our custom DocumentPickerVC.  Turns out in 8.3 and later you have access to self.navigationController and by overriding the property you break Apples dismissal functions.